# Перейти к следующему в дереве блоку при прокрутке колеса jquery

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

Задумка следующая:
Есть несколько section с классом screen каждая на весь экран

```
<div class="content">
  <section class="screen"></section>
  <section class="screen"></section>
  <section class="screen"></section>
</div>

.screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

При прокрутке колесика мыши вниз/вверх должен происходить переход к следующей/предыдущей .screen. Как бы покадровая прокрутка без скрола. Начал с mousewheel а вот что вместо alert ставить никак не дойду

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0)
      alert('up');      
    else
      alert('down');
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0)
      alert('up');
    else 
      alert('down');
    return false;
});
```

```css
.screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <section class="screen">first section</section>
  <section class="screen">second section</section>
  <section class="screen">third section</section>
</div>
```

Вы допустили опечатку со скобочками.

Comment: Спасибо, заодно вопрос скорректировал, заключается именно в переходе с следующему блоку